# Adding flavor to vodka

Tags: flavor, vodka

I accept that one of the easiest ways to add flavor to vodka is simply to add a mixer or juice of some type, but that would be diluting it.  I also know that I can add fruits to the vodka itself which would infuse the vodka with a particular flavor.  Is there another way, say with some type of essential oil of some variety.  Overly sweet flavors should be avoided.

Comment: Very interesting is your question. I guess some Hogwarts flavors may not do well. [The Most Insane Candies At The Wizarding World of Harry Potter](http://www.delish.com/restaurants/videos/a47344/harry-potter-candy/) Hope you get some good answers, as I would like to try this.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to add fruit?

Comment: I think I can just about do the fruit thing myself without having to ask how to do it, thus wanting to know other ways of doing it.

Comment: Adding just the peel of citrus fruits add lots of flavor without diluting.

Comment: @Eric Shain.  That is an excellent comment/answer, and believe it or not I hadn't thought of just the peel.  Many thanks for that - brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They make the exact product you are looking for. Home Distillers can add flavorings to their neutral spirits with these products. [Still Spirits](https://stillspirits.com/collections/vodka-shotz) I would look around the website as there are many different types of flavorings if you are interested.

[image]

Comment: I think I have my answer, many thanks I will go off and have a look now.

Comment: I also wanted to say that most fruit extracts in the supermarket are like 80 proof. Pure essence of fruit and alcohol. I really don't know how stores can sell them without going through proper liquor channels (in the USA). Just don't tell the kiddos, they'll start drinking them! https://www.mccormick.com/spices-and-flavors/extracts-and-food-colors/extracts

Comment: Both kids grown up and can now buy their own and not drink mine!  I don't have a problem with adding alcohol to alcohol! Hick!!

Comment: Just an update:  I have some vodka steeping with some lemon and orange peel - will test/taste it daily to see what the results are - hick ;)!

Comment: I have steeped my vodka, wow, the aroma is powerful, and tasted it this morning (only a tiny sip!), decided that it was a bit too bitter.  So, not wanting to waste anything I have added some sweetener, yes good old fashioned splenda (ok the supermarkets own brand), and hey presto, I have a very nice drink.  I think that it could do with only being steeped for a day and no more than 2, but all the same a very good outcome.

Comment: Why have I now go a headache!?

Answer (score 4):

It's incredibly easy to [infuse vodka with tea](http://www.mademan.com/mm/how-infuse-vodka-tea.html) - unscrew the cap, force a teabag through the neck, screw the cap back on, and put it in the freezer until you're happy with it (overnight is fine). Keep the tag outside so it's easy to pull out. Tea vodka is tasty, and also makes a great base for cocktails.

You can also infuse it with [horseradish](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/8406-horseradish-vodka), or ginger, or any other kind of root the same way that you would with a fruit peel - slice it thin, chuck it in, and give it a day. Unsweetened cranberries are great, and cranberry vodka is very popular in Russia and Finland.

With the right infusions, you can turn your vodka into [gin](https://www.craftginclub.co.uk/ginnedmagazine/2016/5/11/how-to-make-your-own-gin-at-home-no-still-required).

Comment: Not sure about the tea vodka, I might get confused and drink it for breakfast!  But hey ho, I'll give it a try thanks. (the making - not drinking for breakfast)

Answer (score 4):

I know of two methods:

1. Add some aroma-containing plant-material (herbs, spices, fruit-peel, ...) into a bottle of vodka and let it rest to infuse. Remove when desired taste is achieved. An infusion with [bison grass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierochloe_odorata) is well known in Poland as [Zubrowka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%BBubr%C3%B3wka). Some examples:

   - lemongrass
   - sage (mix result with lime-juice and sugar)
   - orange-peel
   - juniper (that's kind of how gin is made, i fact just look at a list of [gin-botanicals](http://www.annodistillers.co.uk/content/dry-gin-botanicals) to get ideas)
   - rosemary
   - cinnamon
   - safron
2. Dissolve some candy in a bottle of vodka. Where i come from a handful of blue mint cooler candy dissolved in vodka is called "*smurf pee*".  Just use real candy made from real sugar and all the flavours are yours. It tastes awfully artificial, but a lot of people like it.

Answer (score 2):

[Simple Syrups](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/20216/simple-syrup/) can be a great way to infuse other flavors into your vodka. To add other flavors, you would add them into the simple syrup, mashing as you go along. [You have to consider](http://byo.com/hops/item/679-fruit-brew-part-2-techniques) the temperature and amount of fruit to add to get the desired flavor. If you are trying to follow the simple syrup recipe and bring the sugar/water/additives to a boil ASAP, you shouldn't really lose any flavor.

From personal experience (and preference), strain the simple syrup with a [cheese cloth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000VLVBQ), or other straining device ([chinoise](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/10-bouillon-chinois-strainer/40740PN.html?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GoogleShopping&gclid=CLKBhdufz9MCFdccgQodKYwLtg) mentioned below). This is especially true when making things like a [Strawberry Habeñero Margarita](http://heatherchristo.com/2014/05/04/strawberry-habanero-margarita/) if you add the seeds in during the simple syrup process.

> Recipe: Strawberry Habanero Margarita
>   Ingredients

```
• ¼ cup Strawberry Habanero Simple Syrup
• ¼ cup Fresh Lime juice
• 4 ounces Grand Marnier
• 4 ounces Tequila
• Strawberry Habanero Simple Syrup:
• 1 cup sugar
• 1 cup water
• 1 cup strawberries
• 1 habanero with seeds
```

> Instructions for Strawberry Habañero Syrup:

```
1. Bring everything to a simmer and let cook for about 5 minutes over medium heat.
2. Strain the syrup through a chinoise and reserve juice. Discard the berries and pepper.
3. Chill the syrup.
```

> Making the drink

```
1. Combine ice, the syrup, the lime juice and the liquor in a cocktail shaker.
2. Shake vigourously and then pour into a chilled ice filled glass. 

    Preparation time: 5 minute(s)

    Cooking time: 5 minute(s)

    Number of servings (yield): 2
```

Granted - you're asking about Vodka infusions... This is my relevant experience with infusions and simple syrups. 10/10 will make this margarita again.

Comment: Thanks for all of that.  At the moment I am staying away from vodka (too many headaches) and am back to the good ol' G&T.  No doubt when my health gets back to normal (no headaches) I will try a few more varieties for my vodkas!

Answer (score 1):

I actually use skittles to add flavor to vodka.The process takes a while to complete the process and get all the flavor. I found instructions that seem to be the equivalent to what I do(except I use coffee filters). Separation of the skittles is key in my opinion but whow knows you may come up with a combination that you really love. I personally just buy a large bag from Amazon.

[Skittle Vodka Tutorial](https://mixthatdrink.com/skittles-vodka-tutorial/)